# Yahtzee, replacing global list with class attribute

Tags: python

I am creating a yahtzee game as a school assignment, Currently I am using a global list in one of my functions and was told this wasn't allowed. I am currently trying to figure out how I can replace the global list in the function:

```
def welcome():
   global spelarlista
   spelarlista=[]
   print("Welcome to the yahtzee game!")
   players = int(input("How many players: "))
   rounds=0
   while not players==rounds:
       player=input("What is your name?: ")
       rounds=rounds+1
       spelarlista.append(Player(player))
```

with a class attribute inside the class Player. Right now the player class is looking like this:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
        self.lista={"aces":0,"twos":0,"threes":0,"fours":0,"fives":0,"sixes":0,"upper score":0,"bonus":0,"pair":0,"two pairs":0,"3 of a kind":0,"4 of a kind":0,"small straight":0,"large straight":0,"full house":0,"chance":0,"yatzy":0,"sum":0}
        self.upper={"aces":0,"twos":0,"threes":0,"fours":0,"fives":0,"sixes":0}
```

as of now I'm using the global spelarlista inside the Player class in several of the methods, and I was hoping I didn't have to replace it all. Is there a way to replace the global spelarlista with something I can call from the player class ?

Comment: Why can't you pass it as an argument to `welcome`?

Comment: created the list spelarlista outside of everything and passed it as an argument to welcome and it worked just fine, thanks for the help!

Comment: If you created `spelarlista` outside of `welcome`, it still sounds like it's a global variable.